# Php receives truncated mysql results

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm experiencing a strange issue while running a mysql query from php.
I have a mysql database with many (23) tables; two of them are Users and FollowersList.
FollowersList contains two colums: in the first one there's the code of a user, and in the second one the code of the user that the first one is following; each column references the primary index of Users table.

I have defined a stored procedure called "getFollowings" that returns the codes of the users that someone is following; it is defined in this way:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getFollowings(IN cod INT(11))    
BEGIN    
SELECT Code2 FROM FollowersList WHERE Code1=cod;    
END
```

When I call the stored procedure from phpmyadmin, everything works fine; I get all the correct results.
When I call it from php, using this code:

```
$sql0="CALL getFollowings('".$cod."')";
$res0=mysqli_query($con, $sql0);
$array0=mysqli_fetch_array($res0);
mysqli_next_result($con);
```

I can't get the correct results. The connection is defined correctly, and all the variables are correctly defined.
Let's make an example. I'm working on the user with code 94; when I run the procedure from phpmyadmin, I get two results: 63 and 89, which is correct in my database.
If I try the same from a php script, I get an array of dimension 2, but with only the first value; the var_dump is:

array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "63" ["Code2"]=> string(2) "63" }

This means that I receive and array with size=2, but with only one element stored. Do you have any idea why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not iterating the mysqli_fetch_array.
Use like this

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res0)){
$array0[] = $row;
}

print_r($array0);
```

and you are using mysqli_fetch_array which give both associative array and numeric array.

If you want associative array use

```
mysqli_fetch_array($res0,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

If you want numeric array use

```
mysqli_fetch_array($res0,MYSQLI_NUM);
```

as default it return both

use like this

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res0)){
$array0[] = $row;
}

echo count($array0);

foreach($array0 as $value){
   echo $value[0];
}
```

Comment: It actually kinda works, but how do I access the stored values?
The output is:
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 63 [Code2] => 63 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 89 [Code2] => 89 ) )
If I try:
'$c=count($array0);
echo $c."<br>";
for ($i = 0; $i < $c; $i++)
{
 echo $array0[$i]."<br>";
} '
I just get a string conversion, and "array" is displayed instead of the required result.

Comment: Yes because its an nested array try echo $array0[$i][0] it will also work. I will update my answer